# How does Date.now() work in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to create a time value I can easily relate to others.

```
var created = Date.now() * 1000

var day_ago = Date.now() * 1000 - 24*60*60

if(created > day_ago){console.log('it was created in the last day')}
```

This doesn't seem to work correctly, anyone know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Oh, should I not be multiplying by 1000?

Comment: Date.now() return a result in miliseconds. 1000ms give 1s, so yes, divide by 1000 give you a result in seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date.now() will return milli seconds devide by 1000 will convert that in seconds.

```
var created = Date.now() / 1000

var day_ago = Date.now()/ 1000 - 24*60*60

if(created > day_ago){console.log('it was created in the last day')}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must divide by 1000, not multiply

```
var created = Date.now() / 1000
var day_ago = Date.now() / 1000 - 24*60*60
if(created > day_ago){console.log('it was created in the last day')}
```